# Parse JSON string using C# script in SSIS

Tags: c#, json, ssis

I am working on retrieving USD -> GBP exchange rates from CurrencyLayer using a C# script task in SSIS. I have used the following code:

```
string url = Dts.Variables["User::CurrencyLayerURL"].Value.ToString();
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
var jsonString = wc.DownloadString(url);
```

To successfully retrieve the following JSON string:

```
{  
   "success":true,
   "terms":"https:\/\/currencylayer.com\/terms",
   "privacy":"https:\/\/currencylayer.com\/privacy",
   "historical":true,
   "date":"2015-11-28",
   "timestamp":1448755199,
   "source":"USD",
   "quotes":{  
      "USDGBP":0.66527
   }
}
```

However, I am not sure at this point how to retrieve just the 0.66527 value that corresponds to the "USDGBP" rate and pass it to a variable. I have seen a number of suggestions to use the JSON.net library, but I am not able to add any third-party libraries to this project. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could keep it simple and just use string parsing to get it out. When your package is mostly C# code you might want to reconsider whether it should be a package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `JsonValue` class from `System.Json Namespace`.

```
JsonValue value = JsonValue.Parse(jsonString);
var quote =  (string)result["quotes"]["USDGBP"];
```

Or you could use the `JavaScriptSerializer` from `System.Web.Script.Serialization`

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var result = serializer.Deserialize<ExpandoObject>(jsonString);
var quote = result.quotes.USDGBP;
```

Or in `Json.Decode` from `System.Web.Helpers`

```
Var result = Json.Decode(jsonString);
var quote = result.quotes.USDGBP;
```

Comment: I am not able to find either System.Json Namespace or System.Web.Script.Serialization any chance you can remember what reference you added?

Answer (score 0):

Parse your json object using JSON.NET:

```
dynamic d = JObject.Parse(jsonString );
Console.WriteLine(d.quotes.USDGBP);
```

Comment: I cannot add any third party libraries, so am not able to use JSON.NET

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScriptSerializer You can add Syatem.Web.Extensions namespace reference.

```
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
     //Serialize
     var serializedResult = serializer.Serialize(Object);
     //Deserialize
   var deserializedResult = serializer.Deserialize<OutputObjectType>(jsonString);
```